# VB.NET equivalent of C# property shorthand?

Tags: c#, vb.net, language-features

Is there a VB.NET equivalent to the C#:

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

I know you can do

```
Public Property name() As String
   Get
      Return _name.ToString
   End Get
   Set(ByVal value As String)
       _name = value
   End Set
End Property
```

But I can't seem to google up an answer on a Visual Basic shorthand.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

There is no shorthand for Visual Studio 2008 or prior for VB.NET.

In Visual Studio 2010 and beyond, you can use the following shorthand:

```
Public Property FirstName as String
```

This will be handled as your short version in C# is - I think they call it "Auto Property"

See also: [Auto-Implemented Properties (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx)

Comment: @CRice: Well, without C# auto-properties, the code would be virtually identical (give or take a curly brace).

Comment: @rap, now implement "public string FirstName {get; private set;}" in VB :P

Comment: Add up all the semi-colons, I'm sure it evens out

Comment: I would say, you need to specify the `.Net` version rather than the Visual Studio version

Answer (score 22):

In Visual Studio 2008, after typing just the keyword `Property`, press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. It'll paste a template snippet for you which you can fill very quickly.

But yeah, there is not a replacement of a Visual Basic 10-type shortcut in Visual Basic 9.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Visual Basic 9 (which ships with .NET 3.5/Visual Studio 2008) does not have automatic properties.