# Does VB.NET support automatic getters and setters on properties?

Tags: vb.net, properties, c#-to-vb.net

In C# I can do this:

```
public string myProperty { get; private set; }
```

This is referred to as an "automatic getter/setter" (from what I've heard). Does VB.NET support these? So far, with my properties, all I can do is this:

```
Public Property myProperty As String
    Get
        Return String.Empty
    End Get
    Private Set(ByVal value As String)
        somethingElse = value
    End Set
End Property
```

which is extremely clunky.

So... is there a better way?

Comment: Take a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460027/vb-net-equivalent-of-c-property-shorthand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460027/vb-net-equivalent-of-c-property-shorthand)

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.net equivalent of C# Property Shorthand?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460027/vb-net-equivalent-of-c-property-shorthand)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes.

```
Public Property MyProperty As String
```

However, you can only make it `ReadOnly` in VB 14 (vs 2015) or later.

Comment: Ah, that was my real question... I forgot to specify I meant using different scopes on get vs. set (like `get; private set;` for example), but you answered that anyway, since you can't make it ReadOnly. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you can [make it readonly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) starting with 2015.

Answer (score 2):

It does but only from framework 4.0 (2010)

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/01/net-framework-4-0-vb-net-supports-automatic-properties.aspx