# Hiding variables

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Quick silly question: is it possible to hide a variable name used by a property in VB.NET?

I am primarily a C# programmer, and am currently helping out a friend with some VB.NET stuff. Anyway, I have a String called `stateprovincename`, and a Property called `StateProvinceName`. VS does not appear to like this naming convention, and declares that they are in fact one and the same. Ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VB.Net is [case-insensitve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300983/is-vb-really-case-insensitive).

- Try something like `_stateProvinceName` or `mStateProvinceName` (discussion of naming conventions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526346/naming-conventions-for-private-members-of-net-types)).
- Or use an [automatic property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582836/does-vb-net-support-automatic-getters-and-setters-on-properties), which will implicitly declare a hidden backing variable, but you won't be able to write custom code in the `Get` and `Set`. `Public Property StateProvinceName As String`

Comment: +1. Case-insensitivity is cool in VB.NET. I'm tired of C# constructs like `public Public publiC() {}` BTW, Microsoft standard is lower [camel casing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), like this: `_tableLayoutSettings` (notice first letter is small).

Answer (score 1):

VB.Net unlike most other languages is not case sensitive with variable names, so standard convention would be add some kind of prefix to the local as to distinguish it from the property.