# Generate class from database table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I generate a class from a SQL Server table object?

I'm not talking about using some ORM. I just need to create the entities (simple class). Something like:

```cs
    public class Person 
    {
        public string Name { get;set; }
        public string Phone { get;set; }
    }
```

Given some table like:

```
+----+-------+----------------+
| ID | Name  |     Phone      |
+----+-------+----------------+
|  1 | Alice | (555) 555-5550 |
|  2 | Bob   | (555) 555-5551 |
|  3 | Cathy | (555) 555-5552 |
+----+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: Why not let Entity Framework generate the classes for you, but just don't use the classes that have to do with database access?

Comment: I couldn't agree with @John Saunders more.  I've done it manually myself in the past, but it's just too time-consuming.  EF just does it right the first time in most cases.  If not, tweaking the generated classes is so much less time-consuming than doing it all yourself.  I have better things to do with my time than write code that an ORM generator can do for me.  I understand a dislike for generated code, but the trade-off in time (and cost) savings is so worth it, at least for me.

Comment: I think EF would indeed be the best solution. Another possibility would be LINQ to sql Classes. 

You just add it to your project and give it a database connection.
Next you just select the tables you need and it will make some classes for you.

Comment: In practice, EF is not always the best solution in every case. For one example, there could be several inexperienced developers who make crass changes to the edmx file which cause version conflicts to say the least... Also, the option may not always be available either. For example, the technical lead simply may not want you to use it for whatever reason.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/joey-qc/6710702

Comment: Try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225503/generate-c-sharp-class-from-sql-server-table/56956498#56956498

Comment: I needed this because I work with a third party database which have more than 2000 tables and absolutely no keys whatsoever. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
And Entity Framework cannot scaffold a database with no keys.

Comment: This is in fact an off-topic request for an external tool.

Comment: Forget all the answers below. Just use the power of EF and .Net6 tools, which were built for this.

Comment: The answers are doing too much. IMHO, the simplest way  is to just open Package Manager Console  and type this: `Scaffold-DbContext "Server=servername.com;Database=DbName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir "Models/Entities" -DataAnnotations -Tables Person`. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=vs.

Answer (score 913, accepted):

Set @TableName to the name of your table.

```
declare @TableName sysname = 'TableName'
declare @Result varchar(max) = 'public class ' + @TableName + '
{'

select @Result = @Result + '
    public ' + ColumnType + NullableSign + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get; set; }
'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id ColumnId,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'double'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'string'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'float'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'long'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end ColumnType,
        case 
            when col.is_nullable = 1 and typ.name in ('bigint', 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money', 'numeric', 'real', 'smalldatetime', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'time', 'tinyint', 'uniqueidentifier') 
            then '?' 
            else '' 
        end NullableSign
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t
order by ColumnId

set @Result = @Result  + '
}'

print @Result
```

Comment: Bigint should go to Int64: [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx), and most people will probably need a switch for nullable types as well.

Comment: @TimLehner - 'long' is C# alias for Int64 .NET framework type. In other words this is the same type. I agree about nullable types. The query was a just a quick sample that just expresses an idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex! To make this work I had to add another filter to my 'where' clause: 'and typ.name NOT LIKE 'usrtyp%''. Hope this saves someone 5 minutes :)

Comment: For **Nullable Types**, append this code between `end` and `ColumnType` in Alex's SQL script.


    `+ CASE WHEN col.is_nullable=1 AND typ.name NOT IN ('binary', 'varbinary', 'image', 'text', 'ntext', 'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'nchar') THEN '?' ELSE '' END`

Comment: Also, you should add to the join clause: `AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id` because there may be more than one row with the same system_type_id ([for example, both sysname and nvarchar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15642374/7913)). In debugging this, I also added an `else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name` to the CASE clause, which may be handy for future reference (without that, it adds NULL and just returns no output). (Edit: I modified Alex's answer with these fixes)

Comment: Is it possible to generate code for a C# method that populates a List of POCO class using  SqlDataReader? That would complement this utility in an excellent manner.

Comment: @AlexAza you should change "when '`float' then 'float'`" to "`when 'float' then 'double'` and you should change "`when 'real' then 'double'`" to "`when 'real' then 'float'`." It seems you got those types confused. The C# equivalent to a SQL float is a double and the C# equivalent to a SQL real is a float.

Comment: Thanks for this! In it's current state though this answer does not add the "?" for nullable ints or longs.  Please add int and bigint to "type.name in" expression.

Comment: I had a need to do this on a SQL 6.5 database (On SQL Server 2000, using SSMS 2012) so I modified Alex's script to use the information_schema views. Also, I wanted to make it set based because I have some kind of OCD for that :) . May be useful to others: https://gist.github.com/shawndube/8c6dab938729179b11ba

Comment: Very very very handy method in SQL!! +1000 if it were possible

Comment: Nice answer, but you need to change `print @Result` to `print CAST(@Result AS TEXT)` otherwise it gets truncated on large tables.

Comment: @RobertMcKee - First of all TEXT is deprecated type. Secondly type is not the issue here. The issue is with PRINT limit. If you have very large output you can replace the last line with `select cast('<root><![CDATA[' + @Result + ']]></root>' as xml)`. This will not truncate the result as PRINT does.

Comment: @AlexAza Yes, TEXT is a depreciated type in SQL Sever 2016 (they *might* remove it in SQL Server 2018+), and PRINT has a limit -- except for the TEXT type, which doesn't have the same limit.  `as xml` doesn't work in SQL Server 2000, but `print CAST(@Result AS TEXT)` does.  It also doesn't wrap the answer in a xml node, and it doesn't suffer from xml encoding issues (very useful if you want to print some xml), and it doesn't interfere with returned results.  None of which the above does, but those are pitfalls you might need to worry about in other cases.

Comment: Try the following: `DECLARE @r varchar(max);
SET @r='1]]>' + CAST(REPLICATE('x',7996) as varchar(max))+ '1';
PRINT @r;
PRINT CAST(@r as TEXT);
select cast('<root><![CDATA[' + @r + ']]></root>' as xml);`  The first print trucates the answer, the second one works, the third throws an error.

Comment: @RobertMcKee - First of all TEXT type has been deprecated since SQL 2005. Secondly, converting to TEXT does not solve the issue. I tried table with 1024 columns and the result was still truncated after converting to TEXT (I used SSMS 2016), while conversion to XML worked without issues. Thirdly, my script would definitely need some adjustments if you want it to work on SQL 2000 or lower, there was no intention to create a script that works on any SQL version. Fourthly, I don't really follow how your example is related to the topic, I don't see how it would be possible to face this issue.

Comment: @AlexAza Not sure what to tell you, I had the issue, and changed it what I said, and it worked just fine, although I used SSMS 2012, and I've used it on every version of SQL Server from 2005 to 2012 without issue.  Anyhow, thanks for your answer.

Comment: How about adding data annotations for validation to this - eg max field length? :)

Comment: I had to add "SET NOCOUNT ON" since I kept getting "1 Row(s) affected" instead of the desired result.

Comment: I've derived a version to [output all tables of a database as POCOs/models](https://pastebin.com/NUQVLmCs).

Comment: This type of answer always makes me want the 'star an answer' feature

Comment: Do you have a POSTGRESQL equivalent of this?

Comment: I suggest timestamp be converted to byte array `byte[]`.  See MS type mapping table at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

Comment: @Həsən Cəfərov fyi

Comment: This looked awesome and was still super useful, but missed 8 properties out of 40. Just heads up.

Comment: This is amazing! It suits my needs (tables with only primitive data types) just fine. I also extended it to include validation attributes like `Required` and `StringLength`.

Comment: Brilliant....i almost upvoted this before verifying it works!

Comment: For folks who get an empty class, just make sure you've selected the Database at the top of the script (for eg: `USE DbName GO`) or by selecting it in SSMS.

Answer (score 92):

I could not get Alex's answer to work on Sql Server 2008 R2. So, I rewrote it using the same basic principles. It now allows for schemas and several fixes have been made for column-property mappings (including mapping nullable date types to nullable C# value types). Here is the Sql:

```
   DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX) = 'NewsItem' -- Replace 'NewsItem' with your table name
    DECLARE @TableSchema VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Markets' -- Replace 'Markets' with your schema name
    DECLARE @result varchar(max) = ''

    SET @result = @result + 'using System;' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) 

    IF (@TableSchema IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        SET @result = @result + 'namespace ' + @TableSchema  + CHAR(13) + '{' + CHAR(13) 
    END

    SET @result = @result + 'public class ' + @TableName + CHAR(13) + '{' + CHAR(13) 

    SET @result = @result + '#region Instance Properties' + CHAR(13)  

   SELECT
      @result = @result + CHAR(13)
      + ' public ' + ColumnType + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get; set; } ' + CHAR(13)
    FROM (SELECT
      c.COLUMN_NAME AS ColumnName,
      CASE c.DATA_TYPE
        WHEN 'bigint' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int64?'
            ELSE 'Int64'
          END
        WHEN 'binary' THEN 'Byte[]'
        WHEN 'bit' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'bool?'
            ELSE 'bool'
          END
        WHEN 'char' THEN 'string'
        WHEN 'date' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?'
            ELSE 'DateTime'
          END
        WHEN 'datetime' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?'
            ELSE 'DateTime'
          END
        WHEN 'datetime2' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?'
            ELSE 'DateTime'
          END
        WHEN 'datetimeoffset' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTimeOffset?'
            ELSE 'DateTimeOffset'
          END
        WHEN 'decimal' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'decimal?'
            ELSE 'decimal'
          END
        WHEN 'float' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Single?'
            ELSE 'Single'
          END
        WHEN 'image' THEN 'Byte[]'
        WHEN 'int' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'int?'
            ELSE 'int'
          END
        WHEN 'money' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'decimal?'
            ELSE 'decimal'
          END
        WHEN 'nchar' THEN 'string'
        WHEN 'ntext' THEN 'string'
        WHEN 'numeric' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'decimal?'
            ELSE 'decimal'
          END
        WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN 'string'
        WHEN 'real' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Double?'
            ELSE 'Double'
          END
        WHEN 'smalldatetime' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?'
            ELSE 'DateTime'
          END
        WHEN 'smallint' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int16?'
            ELSE 'Int16'
          END
        WHEN 'smallmoney' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'decimal?'
            ELSE 'decimal'
          END
        WHEN 'text' THEN 'string'
        WHEN 'time' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'TimeSpan?'
            ELSE 'TimeSpan'
          END
        WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 'Byte[]'
        WHEN 'tinyint' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Byte?'
            ELSE 'Byte'
          END
        WHEN 'uniqueidentifier' THEN CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
            WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Guid?'
            ELSE 'Guid'
          END
        WHEN 'varbinary' THEN 'Byte[]'
        WHEN 'varchar' THEN 'string'
        ELSE 'Object'
      END AS ColumnType,
      c.ORDINAL_POSITION
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
    AND ISNULL(@TableSchema, c.TABLE_SCHEMA) = c.TABLE_SCHEMA) t
    ORDER BY t.ORDINAL_POSITION

    SET @result = @result + CHAR(13) + '#endregion Instance Properties' + CHAR(13)  

    SET @result = @result  + '}' + CHAR(13)

    IF (@TableSchema IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        SET @result = @result + CHAR(13) + '}' 
    END

    PRINT @result
```

It produces C# like the following:

```
using System;

namespace Markets
{
    public class NewsItem        {
        #region Instance Properties

        public Int32 NewsItemID { get; set; }

        public Int32? TextID { get; set; }

        public String Description { get; set; }

        #endregion Instance Properties
    }

}
```

It may be an idea to use EF, Linq to Sql, or even Scaffolding; however, there are times when a piece of coding like this comes in handy. Frankly, I do not like using EF navigation properties where the code it generates made 19,200 separate database calls to populate a 1000 row grid. This could have been achieved in a single database call. Nonetheless, it could just be that your technical architect does not want you to use EF and the like. So, you have to revert to code like this... Incidentally, it may also be an idea to decorate each of the properties with attributes for DataAnnotations, etc., but I'm keeping this strictly POCO.

**EDIT**
Fixed for *TimeStamp* and *Guid?*

Comment: +1, this worked well for me too. I'm using EF for our main db but need to grab a sproc from another db and didn't want to code up an entire EF project for that, so this let me quickly create a class to accomodate my sproc resultset...thanks

Comment: I still use it now but I've included MVC property attributes for string length, etc.

Comment: Produces Empty Class for me with no properties/columns.

Comment: @highwingers: Are you using a valid schema and table name? Please show me your implementation of the above.

Comment: This is polished one. I am using this. But Thanks to Alex for creating the original one.

Comment: You don't really need Nullable<T> for non-value types. Reference types are nullable by default.

Comment: You want both - I've needed both

Comment: As I specified, this answer relates Sql Server 2008 R2. If you want 2005 then please look at Alex's answer.

Comment: Nice work!:) Can you please fix your timestamp?  Timestamps are not dates, they are actually a binary and have nothing to do with time, the are for row versions.  The correct type is a byte array (byte[]).

Guid's are also incorrect, they should be nullable if nullable in the database.

Comment: A tweak to iterate through all user tables in the database would be awesome ;)

Comment: Great. This is a good upgrade from the above solution. Thanks.

Comment: Now to tweak it to handle DateTime2 and add [ColumnType(TypeName = "datetime2")]. And to add string length attributes, such as [StringLength(50)].

Comment: @Rhyous I'm not decorating the class. I'm keeping it strictly POCO.

Comment: @TheMiddleMan Done

Comment: @highwingers If you get an empty class, just make sure you've selected the Database at the top of the script (for eg: `USE DbName GO`) or by selecting it in SSMS.

Answer (score 22):

VB version

```
declare @TableName sysname = 'myTableName'
declare @prop varchar(max)
PRINT 'Public Class ' + @TableName
declare props cursor for
select distinct ' public property ' + ColumnName + ' AS ' + ColumnType AS prop
from ( 
    select  
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,  column_id, 
        case typ.name  
            when 'bigint' then 'long' 
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]' 
            when 'bit' then 'boolean' 
            when 'char' then 'string' 
            when 'date' then 'DateTime' 
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime' 
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime' 
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset' 
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal' 
            when 'float' then 'float' 
            when 'image' then 'byte[]' 
            when 'int' then 'integer' 
            when 'money' then 'decimal' 
            when 'nchar' then 'char' 
            when 'ntext' then 'string' 
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal' 
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string' 
            when 'real' then 'double' 
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime' 
            when 'smallint' then 'short' 
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal' 
            when 'text' then 'string' 
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan' 
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime' 
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte' 
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid' 
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]' 
            when 'varchar' then 'string' 
        end ColumnType 
    from sys.columns col join sys.types typ on col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id 
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName) 
) t 
order by prop
open props
FETCH NEXT FROM props INTO @prop
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    print @prop
    FETCH NEXT FROM props INTO @prop
END
close props
DEALLOCATE props
PRINT 'End Class'
```

Comment: @highwingers since Visual Studio 2010, they aren't required http://stackoverflow.com/a/460032/618186

Comment: I had to add the "use MyDatabase" text at the top to work right. Otherwise it would generate a couple of unrecognizable class properties.

Comment: Very nice. But `float` should go to `Double`, `byte[]` to `Byte()`

Comment: Nicely done. I even tried a view and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 20):

A bit late but I've created a web tool to help create a C# (or other) objects from SQL result, SQL Table and SQL SP.

[sql2object.com](https://www.sql2object.com)

This can really safe you having to type all your properties and types.

If the types are not recognised the default will be selected.

Comment: not bad but it can't use table definition script as source

Comment: This is great :) It's great that it works for both results and tables.
Would be really nice if you could modify it to just ignore all the `CREATE TABLE` stuff so I can cut and paste everything. Also if you get a chance can you add a 'Trim()' in there - it fails if there's a blank line at the beginning and then people will give up on it. Simple if you know to remove it - but you'll lose people when you give an error.

Comment: Also what's the format for a SQL result set. I just copy and paste from a text output window and it gives me one single field containing all the column names :-/ What's the trick?

Comment: or you can make it open source and let community build it up the way they want it.

Comment: It doesn't create C# class from "Create Table " script,

Comment: For those using SSMS, select a couple of rows from the table of interest, go to the results (grid mode) and Copy with headers -> paste in the tool and it should directly work.

Answer (score 14):

I'm trying to give my 2 cents

0) QueryFirst
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst
[image]
*Query-first is a visual studio extension for working intelligently with SQL in C# projects. Use the provided .sql template to develop your queries. When you save the file, Query-first runs your query, retrieves the schema and generates two classes and an interface: a wrapper class with methods Execute(), ExecuteScalar(), ExecuteNonQuery() etc, its corresponding interface, and a POCO encapsulating a line of results.*

**1) Sql2Objects** 
Creates the class starting from the result of a query (but not the DAL)
[image]

**2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/resources/tools**
[image]

**3) https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/12/11/sqlqueryresults-code-generation.aspx**
[image]

**4) http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator#features**

Comment: I like 3, I don't have to put anything into my projects for EF, I can keep it in this little project.

Answer (score 11):

To print out NULLABLE properties, use this.
It adds a slight modification to Alex Aza's script for the `CASE` statement block.

```
declare @TableName sysname = 'TableName'
declare @result varchar(max) = 'public class ' + @TableName + '
{'

select @result = @result + '
    public ' + ColumnType + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get; set; }
'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'char'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end + 
        CASE
            WHEN col.is_nullable=1 AND
                 typ.name NOT IN (
                     'binary', 'varbinary', 'image',
                     'text', 'ntext',
                     'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'nchar')
            THEN '?'
            ELSE '' END AS [ColumnType]
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id 
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t
order by column_id

set @result = @result  + '
}'

print @result
```

Answer (score 9):

Yea these are great if your using a simple ORM like Dapper.

If your using .Net you can generate an XSD file at run time with any DataSet using the WriteXmlSchema method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt7k72x8(v=vs.110).aspx

*Like this:*

```
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(mConnStr)) {
DataSet Data = new DataSet();
cnn.Open();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Person";

using (SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn))
{
try
{
    Da.Fill(Data);
    Da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Person");
    Data.WriteXmlSchema(@"C:\Person.xsd");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
}
cnn.Close();
```

From there you can use xsd.exe to create a class that's XML serializable from the Developer Command Prompt. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx

*like this:*

```
xsd C:\Person.xsd /classes /language:CS
```

Answer (score 7):

If you have access to SQL Server 2016, you can use the FOR JSON (with INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES) option to get JSON output from a select statement. Copy the output, then in Visual Studio, paste special -> paste JSON as class.

Kind of a budget solution, but might save some time.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to use the suggestions above and in the process improved upon the solutions in this thread.

Let us say you use a base class (ObservableObject in this case) that implements the PropertyChanged Event, you would do something like this. I will probably write a blog post one day in my blog 
sqljana.wordpress.com

Please do substitute the values for the first three variables:

```
    --These three things have to be substituted (when called from Powershell, they are replaced before execution)
DECLARE @Schema VARCHAR(MAX) = N'&Schema'
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX) = N'&TableName'
DECLARE @Namespace VARCHAR(MAX) = N'&Namespace'

DECLARE @CRLF VARCHAR(2) = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(max) = ' '

DECLARE @PrivateProp VARCHAR(100) = @CRLF + 
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + 'private <ColumnType> _<ColumnName>;';
DECLARE @PublicProp VARCHAR(255) = @CRLF + 
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + 'public <ColumnType> <ColumnName> '  + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '{ ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '   get { return _<ColumnName>; } ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '   set ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '   { ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '       _<ColumnName> = value;' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '       base.RaisePropertyChanged();' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '   } ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '}' + @CRLF;

DECLARE @RPCProc VARCHAR(MAX) = @CRLF +         
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + 'public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + 'private void RaisePropertyChanged( ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '       [CallerMemberName] string caller = "" ) ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '{  ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '   if (PropertyChanged != null)  ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '   { ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '       PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( caller ) );  ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '   } ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '}';

DECLARE @PropChanged VARCHAR(200) =  @CRLF +            
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + 'protected override void AfterPropertyChanged(string propertyName) ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '{ ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("' + @TableName + ' property changed: " + propertyName); ' + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + '}';

SET @result = 'using System;' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                'using MyCompany.Business;' + @CRLF + @CRLF +
                'namespace ' + @Namespace  + @CRLF + '{' + @CRLF +
                '   public class ' + @TableName + ' : ObservableObject' + @CRLF + 
                '   {' + @CRLF +
                '   #region Instance Properties' + @CRLF 

SELECT @result = @result
                 + 
                REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(@PrivateProp
                            , '<ColumnName>', ColumnName)
                        , '<ColumnType>', ColumnType)
                +                           
                REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(@PublicProp
                            , '<ColumnName>', ColumnName)
                        , '<ColumnType>', ColumnType)                   
FROM
(
    SELECT  c.COLUMN_NAME   AS ColumnName 
        , CASE c.DATA_TYPE   
            WHEN 'bigint' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int64?' ELSE 'Int64' END
            WHEN 'binary' THEN 'Byte[]'
            WHEN 'bit' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Boolean?' ELSE 'Boolean' END            
            WHEN 'char' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'date' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                        
            WHEN 'datetime' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                        
            WHEN 'datetime2' THEN  
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                        
            WHEN 'datetimeoffset' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTimeOffset?' ELSE 'DateTimeOffset' END                                    
            WHEN 'decimal' THEN  
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                    
            WHEN 'float' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Single?' ELSE 'Single' END                                    
            WHEN 'image' THEN 'Byte[]'
            WHEN 'int' THEN  
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int32?' ELSE 'Int32' END
            WHEN 'money' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                                
            WHEN 'nchar' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'ntext' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'numeric' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                                            
            WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'real' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Double?' ELSE 'Double' END                                                                        
            WHEN 'smalldatetime' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                                    
            WHEN 'smallint' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int16?' ELSE 'Int16'END            
            WHEN 'smallmoney' THEN  
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                                                        
            WHEN 'text' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'time' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'TimeSpan?' ELSE 'TimeSpan' END                                                                                    
            WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                                    
            WHEN 'tinyint' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Byte?' ELSE 'Byte' END                                                
            WHEN 'uniqueidentifier' THEN 'Guid'
            WHEN 'varbinary' THEN 'Byte[]'
            WHEN 'varchar' THEN 'String'
            ELSE 'Object'
        END AS ColumnType
        , c.ORDINAL_POSITION 
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE   c.TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
    AND ISNULL(@Schema, c.TABLE_SCHEMA) = c.TABLE_SCHEMA  
) t
ORDER BY t.ORDINAL_POSITION

SELECT @result = @result + @CRLF + 
                CHAR(9) + '#endregion Instance Properties' + @CRLF +
                --CHAR(9) + @RPCProc + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + @PropChanged + @CRLF +
                CHAR(9) + '}' + @CRLF +
                @CRLF + '}' 
--SELECT @result
PRINT @result
```

The base class is based on Josh Smith's article here
From http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/08/29/a-base-class-which-implements-inotifypropertychanged/

I did rename the class to be called ObservableObject and also took advantage of a c# 5 feature using the CallerMemberName attribute

```
//From http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/08/29/a-base-class-which-implements-inotifypropertychanged/
//
//Jana's change: Used c# 5 feature to bypass passing in the property name using [CallerMemberName] 
//  protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace MyCompany.Business
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and 
    /// exposes a RaisePropertyChanged method for derived 
    /// classes to raise the PropertyChange event.  The event 
    /// arguments created by this class are cached to prevent 
    /// managed heap fragmentation.
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Data

        private static readonly Dictionary<string, PropertyChangedEventArgs> eventArgCache;
        private const string ERROR_MSG = "{0} is not a public property of {1}";

        #endregion // Data

        #region Constructors

        static ObservableObject()
        {
            eventArgCache = new Dictionary<string, PropertyChangedEventArgs>();
        }

        protected ObservableObject()
        {
        }

        #endregion // Constructors

        #region Public Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when a public property of this object is set.
        /// </summary>
        [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an instance of PropertyChangedEventArgs for 
        /// the specified property name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">
        /// The name of the property to create event args for.
        /// </param>        
        public static PropertyChangedEventArgs
            GetPropertyChangedEventArgs(string propertyName)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "propertyName cannot be null or empty.");

            PropertyChangedEventArgs args;

            // Get the event args from the cache, creating them
            // and adding to the cache if necessary.
            lock (typeof(ObservableObject))
            {
                bool isCached = eventArgCache.ContainsKey(propertyName);
                if (!isCached)
                {
                    eventArgCache.Add(
                        propertyName,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }

                args = eventArgCache[propertyName];
            }

            return args;
        }

        #endregion // Public Members

        #region Protected Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Derived classes can override this method to
        /// execute logic after a property is set. The 
        /// base implementation does nothing.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">
        /// The property which was changed.
        /// </param>
        protected virtual void AfterPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to raise the PropertyChanged event, and 
        /// invokes the virtual AfterPropertyChanged method, 
        /// regardless of whether the event was raised or not.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">
        /// The property which was changed.
        /// </param>
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            this.VerifyProperty(propertyName);

            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                // Get the cached event args.
                PropertyChangedEventArgs args =
                    GetPropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);

                // Raise the PropertyChanged event.
                handler(this, args);
            }

            this.AfterPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        #endregion // Protected Members

        #region Private Helpers

        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        private void VerifyProperty(string propertyName)
        {
            Type type = this.GetType();

            // Look for a public property with the specified name.
            PropertyInfo propInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

            if (propInfo == null)
            {
                // The property could not be found,
                // so alert the developer of the problem.

                string msg = string.Format(
                    ERROR_MSG,
                    propertyName,
                    type.FullName);

                Debug.Fail(msg);
            }
        }

        #endregion // Private Helpers
    }
}
```

Here is the part that you guys are going to like some more. I built a Powershell script to generate for all the tables in a SQL database. It is based on a Powershell guru named Chad Miller's Invoke-SQLCmd2 cmdlet which can be downloaded from here:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/7985b7ef-ed89-4dfd-b02a-433cc4e30894/

Once you have that cmdlet, the Powershell script to generate for all tables becomes simple (do substitute the variables with your specific values).

```
. C:\MyScripts\Invoke-Sqlcmd2.ps1

$serverInstance = "MySQLInstance"
$databaseName = "MyDb"
$generatorSQLFile = "C:\MyScripts\ModelGen.sql" 
$tableListSQL = "SELECT name FROM $databaseName.sys.tables"
$outputFolder = "C:\MyScripts\Output\"
$namespace = "MyCompany.Business"

$placeHolderSchema = "&Schema"
$placeHolderTableName = "&TableName"
$placeHolderNamespace = "&Namespace"

#Get the list of tables in the database to generate c# models for
$tables = Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $databaseName -Query $tableListSQL -As DataRow -Verbose

foreach ($table in $tables)
{
    $table1 = $table[0]
    $outputFile = "$outputFolder\$table1.cs"


    #Replace variables with values (returns an array that we convert to a string to use as query)
    $generatorSQLFileWSubstitutions = (Get-Content $generatorSQLFile).
                                            Replace($placeHolderSchema,"dbo").
                                            Replace($placeHolderTableName, $table1).
                                            Replace($placeHolderNamespace, $namespace) | Out-String

    "Ouputing for $table1 to $outputFile"

    #The command generates .cs file content for model using "PRINT" statements which then gets written to verbose output (stream 4)
    # ...capture the verbose output and redirect to a file
    (Invoke-Sqlcmd2 -ServerInstance $serverInstance -Database $databaseName -Query $generatorSQLFileWSubstitutions -Verbose) 4> $outputFile

}
```

Comment: Its been more than 3 years since i asked this and i don't work with sql databases at this moment (big data, mongodb, etc). But i'll surely test this soon, you had a great time elaborating this answer and contributing to the community.
Thank you much!

Comment: I have been using StackOverflow for a long time but only now started contributing. So, you can say that I am starting to learn the S.O. etiquette too. When I was looking for a solution like this, I stumbled upon this thread and just added my extended solution so that future users can benefit from it. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to do all of this in a tsql script - rather than use powershell?

Answer (score 5):

create PROCEDURE for create custom code using template

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[createCode]
(   
   @TableName sysname = '',
   @befor varchar(max)='public class  @TableName  
{',
   @templet varchar(max)=' 
     public @ColumnType @ColumnName   { get; set; }  // @ColumnDesc  ',
   @after varchar(max)='
}'

)
AS
BEGIN 


declare @result varchar(max)

set @befor =replace(@befor,'@TableName',@TableName)

set @result=@befor

select @result = @result 
+ replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@templet,'@ColumnType',ColumnType) ,'@ColumnName',ColumnName) ,'@ColumnDesc',ColumnDesc),'@ISPK',ISPK),'@max_length',max_length)

from  
(
    select 
    column_id,
    replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
    typ.name as sqltype,
    typ.max_length,
    is_identity,
    pkk.ISPK, 
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'String'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'char'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'String'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'String'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        END + CASE WHEN col.is_nullable=1 AND typ.name NOT IN ('binary', 'varbinary', 'image', 'text', 'ntext', 'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'nchar') THEN '?' ELSE '' END ColumnType,
      isnull(colDesc.colDesc,'') AS ColumnDesc 
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
            left join
            (
                SELECT c.name  AS 'ColumnName', CASE WHEN dd.pk IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END ISPK           
                FROM        sys.columns c
                    JOIN    sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id    
                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT   K.COLUMN_NAME , C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE as pk  
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS K 
                            LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS C
                        ON K.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
                            AND K.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                            AND K.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = C.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
                            AND K.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA            
                        WHERE K.TABLE_NAME = @TableName) as dd
                     ON dd.COLUMN_NAME = c.name
                 WHERE       t.name = @TableName       
            ) pkk  on ColumnName=col.name

    OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 CAST(value AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS colDesc
    FROM
       sys.extended_properties
    WHERE
       major_id = col.object_id
       AND
       minor_id = COLUMNPROPERTY(major_id, col.name, 'ColumnId')
    ) colDesc      
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)

    ) t

    set @result=@result+@after

    select @result
    --print @result

END
```

---

now create custom code

for example c# class

```
exec [createCode] @TableName='book',@templet =' 
     public @ColumnType @ColumnName   { get; set; }  // @ColumnDesc  '
```

output is

```
public class  book  
{ 
     public long ID   { get; set; }  //    
     public String Title   { get; set; }  // Book Title  
}
```

for LINQ

```
exec [createCode] @TableName='book'
, @befor  ='[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table(Name = "@TableName")]
public class @TableName
{',

   @templet  =' 
     [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "@ColumnName", IsPrimaryKey = @ISPK)]
     public @ColumnType @ColumnName   { get; set; }  // @ColumnDesc  
     ' ,

   @after  ='
}'
```

output is

```
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table(Name = "book")]
public class book
{ 
     [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "ID", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
     public long ID   { get; set; }  //   

     [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "Title", IsPrimaryKey = false)]
     public String Title   { get; set; }  // Book Title  

}
```

for java class

```
exec [createCode] @TableName='book',@templet =' 
     public @ColumnType @ColumnName ; // @ColumnDesc  
     public @ColumnType get@ColumnName()
     {
        return this.@ColumnName;
     }
     public void set@ColumnName(@ColumnType @ColumnName)
     {
        this.@ColumnName=@ColumnName;
     }

     '
```

output is

```
public class  book  
{ 
     public long ID ; //   
     public long getID()
     {
        return this.ID;
     }
     public void setID(long ID)
     {
        this.ID=ID;
     }


     public String Title ; // Book Title  
     public String getTitle()
     {
        return this.Title;
     }
     public void setTitle(String Title)
     {
        this.Title=Title;
     } 
}
```

for android sugarOrm model

```
exec [createCode] @TableName='book'
, @befor  ='@Table(name = "@TableName")
public class @TableName
{',
   @templet  =' 
     @Column(name = "@ColumnName")
     public @ColumnType @ColumnName ;// @ColumnDesc  
     ' ,
   @after  ='
}'
```

output is

```
@Table(name = "book")
public class book
{ 
     @Column(name = "ID")
     public long ID ;//   

     @Column(name = "Title")
     public String Title ;// Book Title  

}
```

Answer (score 3):

To print out NULLABLE properties WITH COMMENTS (Summary), use this.
It is a slight modification of first answer

```
declare @TableName sysname = 'TableName'
declare @result varchar(max) = 'public class ' + @TableName + '
{'
select @result = @result 
+ CASE WHEN ColumnDesc IS NOT NULL THEN '
    /// <summary>
    /// ' + ColumnDesc + '
    /// </summary>' ELSE '' END
+ '
    public ' + ColumnType + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get; set; }'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'String'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'char'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'String'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'String'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        END + CASE WHEN col.is_nullable=1 AND typ.name NOT IN ('binary', 'varbinary', 'image', 'text', 'ntext', 'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'nchar') THEN '?' ELSE '' END ColumnType,
        colDesc.colDesc AS ColumnDesc
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
    OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 CAST(value AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS colDesc
    FROM
       sys.extended_properties
    WHERE
       major_id = col.object_id
       AND
       minor_id = COLUMNPROPERTY(major_id, col.name, 'ColumnId')
    ) colDesc            
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t
order by column_id

set @result = @result  + '
}'

print @result
```

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio Magazine published this:

[Generating .NET POCO Classes for SQL Query Results](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/12/11/sqlqueryresults-code-generation.aspx)

It has a downloadable project that you can build, give it your SQL info, and it will crank out the class for you.

Now if that tool just created the SQL Commands for SELECT, INSERT, and UPDATE....

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I'd add my own variation of the top answer for anyone who's interested.
The main features are:

- It will automatically generate classes for all the tables in the entire schema. Just specify the schema name.
- It will add System.Data.Linq.Mapping attributes to the class and each property. Useful for anyone using Linq to SQL.

  ```
   declare @TableName sysname
   declare @Result varchar(max)
   declare @schema varchar(20) = 'dbo'
   DECLARE @Cursor CURSOR

   SET @Cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
   SELECT DISTINCT tablename = rc1.TABLE_NAME
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables rc1
   where rc1.TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema

   OPEN @Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @TableName

   WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
   BEGIN
   set @Result = '[Table(Name = "' + @schema + '.' + @TableName + '")]
   public class ' + Replace(@TableName, '$', '_') + '
   {'

   select @Result = @Result + '
       [Column' + PriKey +']
       public ' + ColumnType + NullableSign + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get; set; }
   '
   from
   (
       select 
           replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
           col.column_id ColumnId,
           case typ.name 
               when 'bigint' then 'long'
               when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
               when 'bit' then 'bool'
               when 'char' then 'string'
               when 'date' then 'DateTime'
               when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
               when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
               when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
               when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
               when 'float' then 'double'
               when 'image' then 'byte[]'
               when 'int' then 'int'
               when 'money' then 'decimal'
               when 'nchar' then 'string'
               when 'ntext' then 'string'
               when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
               when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
               when 'real' then 'float'
               when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
               when 'smallint' then 'short'
               when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
               when 'text' then 'string'
               when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
               when 'timestamp' then 'long'
               when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
               when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
               when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
               when 'varchar' then 'string'
               else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
           end ColumnType,
           case 
               when col.is_nullable = 1 and typ.name in ('bigint', 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money', 'numeric', 'real', 'smalldatetime', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'time', 'tinyint', 'uniqueidentifier') 
               then '?' 
               else '' 
           end NullableSign,
           case
               when pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME is not null and ic.column_id is not null then '(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)'
               when pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME is not null then '(IsPrimaryKey = true)'
               when ic.column_id is not null then '(IsDbGenerated = true)'
               else ''
           end PriKey
       from sys.columns col
       join sys.types typ on col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
       left outer join sys.identity_columns ic on ic.column_id = col.column_id and col.object_id = ic.object_id
       left outer join (
           SELECT  K.TABLE_NAME ,
               K.COLUMN_NAME ,
               K.CONSTRAINT_NAME
           FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS C
                   JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS K ON C.TABLE_NAME = K.TABLE_NAME
                                                                    AND C.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = K.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
                                                                    AND C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = K.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                                                                    AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = K.CONSTRAINT_NAME
           where C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
       ) pk on pk.COLUMN_NAME = col.name and pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
       where col.object_id = object_id(@schema + '.' + @TableName)
   ) t
   order by ColumnId

   set @Result = @Result  + '
   }

   '

   print @Result

   FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @TableName
   end

   CLOSE @Cursor DEALLOCATE @Cursor
   GO
  ```

Added 6-29-22: Here's an updated variation for generating models for EF Core (dotNet 6.0).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap] ( @InputString varchar(4000) ) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Index          INT
    DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(4000)

    SET @OutputString = @InputString
    SET @Index = 1

    WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
    BEGIN
        SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
        SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                             ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                        END

        IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
            SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))

        SET @Index = @Index + 1
    END

    RETURN @OutputString
END
go


declare @TableName sysname
declare @Result varchar(max)
declare @schema varchar(20) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @Cursor CURSOR

SET @Cursor = CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT DISTINCT tablename = rc1.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables rc1
where rc1.TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema

OPEN @Cursor FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @TableName

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
set @Result = '[Table("' + @TableName + '", Schema = "' + @schema + '")]
public class ' + Replace(@TableName, '$', '_') + '
{'

select @Result = @Result + '
    [Column("' + ColumnName + '"' + stringType + ')]
    public ' + ColumnType + NullableSign + ' ' + PropertyName + ' { get; set; }
'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        replace(replace([dbo].[InitCap](col.name), ' ', ''), '_', '') PropertyName,
        col.column_id ColumnId,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'double'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'string'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'float'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'long'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end ColumnType,
        case 
            when col.is_nullable = 1
            then '?' 
            else '' 
        end NullableSign,
        case
            when typ.name in ('char', 'nchar', 'nvarchar', 'varchar')
            then ', TypeName = "' + typ.name + '(' + convert(varchar, col.max_length) + ')"'
            else ''
        end stringType
    from sys.columns col
    join sys.types typ on col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
    left outer join sys.identity_columns ic on ic.column_id = col.column_id and col.object_id = ic.object_id
    left outer join (
        SELECT  K.TABLE_NAME ,
            K.COLUMN_NAME ,
            K.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS C
                JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS K ON C.TABLE_NAME = K.TABLE_NAME
                                                                 AND C.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = K.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
                                                                 AND C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = K.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                                                                 AND C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = K.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        where C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    ) pk on pk.COLUMN_NAME = col.name and pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
    where col.object_id = object_id(@schema + '.' + @TableName)
) t
order by ColumnId

set @Result = @Result  + '
}

'

print @Result

FETCH NEXT FROM @Cursor INTO @TableName
end

CLOSE @Cursor DEALLOCATE @Cursor
GO

DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap]
GO
```

Comment: Tks for the ready-to-use cursor over a whole schema, you saved me quite some time!

Answer (score 3):

Since no one mentioned it before, there is also Scaffold-DbContext

In NuGet Package Manager console type the following:

`Scaffold-DbContext "Your Connection String" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir "Output Directory"`

Comment: Honestly in .Net6 this is the ONLY good way to do it. MS takes care of all the classes and methods required. Forget class convertors and SQL procedures. Just use this technique and be done with it!

Answer (score 1):

Commercial, but CodeSmith Generator does that: http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused as to what you want out of this, but here are the general options when designing what you want to design.

1. Using the built-in ORM in your version Visual Studio.
2. Write one yourself, similar to your code example.  As usual, a tutorial is your best friend if you're not sure how.
3. Use an alternative ORM such as [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).

Answer (score 1):

In appreciation to Alex's solution and Guilherme for asking I made this for MySQL to generate C# classes

```
set @schema := 'schema_name';
set @table := 'table_name';
SET group_concat_max_len = 2048;
SELECT 
    concat('public class ', @table, '\n{\n', GROUP_CONCAT(a.property_ SEPARATOR '\n'), '\n}') class_
FROM 
    (select
        CONCAT(
        '\tpublic ',
        case 
            when DATA_TYPE = 'bigint' then 'long'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'BINARY' then 'byte[]'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'bit' then 'bool'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'char' then 'string'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'double' then 'double'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'float' then 'float'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'int' then 'int'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'money' then 'decimal'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'nchar' then 'char'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'ntext' then 'string'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'real' then 'double'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'smallint' then 'short'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'text' then 'string'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when DATA_TYPE = 'varchar' then 'string'
            else '_UNKNOWN_'
        end, ' ', 
        COLUMN_NAME, ' {get; set;}') as property_
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = @table AND table_schema = @schema) a
;
```

> ```
> Thanks Alex and Guilherme!
> ```

Comment: Thanks! I was just looking for this!

Answer (score 1):

Grab [QueryFirst](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaf390af-afc1-4994-a442-ec95923dafcb), visual studio extension that generates wrapper classes from SQL queries. You not only get...

```
public class MyClass{
    public string MyProp{get;set;}
    public int MyNumberProp{get;set;}
    ...
}
```

And as a bonus, it'll throw in...

```
public class MyQuery{
    public static IEnumerable<MyClass>Execute(){}
    public static MyClass GetOne(){}
    ...
}
```

Are you sure you want to base your classes directly on your tables? Tables are a static, normalized data storage notion that belongs in the DB. Classes are dynamic, fluid, disposable, context-specific, perhaps denormalized. Why not write real queries for the data you want for an operation, and let QueryFirst generate the classes from that.

Answer (score 1):

This post has saved me several times. I just want to add my two cents.
For those that dont like to use ORMs, and instead write their own DAL classes, when you have like 20 columns in a table, and 40 different tables with their respective CRUD operations, its painful and a waste of time. I repeated the above code, for generating CRUD methods based on the table entity and properties.

```
 declare @TableName sysname = 'Tablename'
declare @Result varchar(max) = 'public class ' + @TableName + '
{'

select @Result = @Result + '
    public ' + ColumnType + NullableSign + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get; set; }
'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id ColumnId,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'char'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end ColumnType,
        case 
            when col.is_nullable = 1 and typ.name in ('bigint', 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money', 'numeric', 'real', 'smalldatetime', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'time', 'tinyint', 'uniqueidentifier') 
            then '?' 
            else '' 
        end NullableSign
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t
order by ColumnId

set @Result = @Result  + '
}'

print @Result

declare @InitDataAccess varchar(max) = 'public class '+ @TableName +'DataAccess 
{ '

declare @ListStatement varchar(max) ='public List<'+@TableName+'> Get'+@TableName+'List()
{
 String conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionNameInWeb.config"].ConnectionString;
 var itemList = new List<'+@TableName+'>();
          try
            {
                using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conn))
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand
                    {
                        Connection = sqlCon,
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                        CommandText = "StoredProcedureSelectAll"
                    };
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                      var item = new '+@TableName+'();
' 
select @ListStatement = @ListStatement + '
item.'+ ColumnName + '= ('+ ColumnType + NullableSign  +')reader["'+ColumnName+'"];
'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id ColumnId,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'char'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end ColumnType,
        case 
            when col.is_nullable = 1 and typ.name in ('bigint', 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money', 'numeric', 'real', 'smalldatetime', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'time', 'tinyint', 'uniqueidentifier') 
            then '?' 
            else '' 
        end NullableSign
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t
order by ColumnId

select @ListStatement = @ListStatement +'
                        itemList.Add(item);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            return itemList;
        }'

declare @GetIndividual varchar(max) =  
'public '+@TableName+' Get'+@TableName+'()
{
 String conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionNameInWeb.config"].ConnectionString;
 var item = new '+@TableName+'();
          try
            {
                using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conn))
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand
                    {
                        Connection = sqlCon,
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                        CommandText = "StoredProcedureSelectIndividual"
                    };
                     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCriteria", item.id);
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {' 
select @GetIndividual = @GetIndividual + '
item.'+ ColumnName + '= ('+ ColumnType + NullableSign  +')reader["'+ColumnName+'"];
'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id ColumnId,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'char'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end ColumnType,
        case 
            when col.is_nullable = 1 and typ.name in ('bigint', 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money', 'numeric', 'real', 'smalldatetime', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'time', 'tinyint', 'uniqueidentifier') 
            then '?' 
            else '' 
        end NullableSign
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t
order by ColumnId

select @GetIndividual = @GetIndividual +'

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
            return item;
        }'



declare @InsertStatement varchar(max) = 'public void  Insert'+@TableName+'('+@TableName+' item)
{
 String conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionNameInWeb.config"].ConnectionString;

          try
            {
                using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conn))
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand
                    {
                        Connection = sqlCon,
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                        CommandText = "StoredProcedureInsert"
                    };

                    ' 
select @InsertStatement = @InsertStatement + '
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@'+ColumnName+'", item.'+ColumnName+');
'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id ColumnId,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'char'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end ColumnType,
        case 
            when col.is_nullable = 1 and typ.name in ('bigint', 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money', 'numeric', 'real', 'smalldatetime', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'time', 'tinyint', 'uniqueidentifier') 
            then '?' 
            else '' 
        end NullableSign
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t
order by ColumnId

select @InsertStatement = @InsertStatement +'

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }

        }'

declare @UpdateStatement varchar(max) = 'public void  Update'+@TableName+'('+@TableName+' item)
{
 String conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionNameInWeb.config"].ConnectionString;

          try
            {
                using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(conn))
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand
                    {
                        Connection = sqlCon,
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                        CommandText = "StoredProcedureUpdate"
                    };
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdateCriteria", item.Id);
                    ' 
select @UpdateStatement = @UpdateStatement + '
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@'+ColumnName+'", item.'+ColumnName+');
'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id ColumnId,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'char'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end ColumnType,
        case 
            when col.is_nullable = 1 and typ.name in ('bigint', 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money', 'numeric', 'real', 'smalldatetime', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'time', 'tinyint', 'uniqueidentifier') 
            then '?' 
            else '' 
        end NullableSign
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t
order by ColumnId

select @UpdateStatement = @UpdateStatement +'

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }

        }'

declare @EndDataAccess varchar(max)  = '
}'
 print @InitDataAccess
 print @GetIndividual
print @InsertStatement
print @UpdateStatement
print @ListStatement
print @EndDataAccess
```

Of course its not bulletproof code, and can be improved. Just wanted to contribute to this excelent solution

Answer (score 1):

slightly modified from top reply:

```
declare @TableName sysname = 'HistoricCommand'

declare @Result varchar(max) = '[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table(Name = "' + @TableName + '")]
public class Dbo' + @TableName + '
{'

select @Result = @Result + '
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "' + t.ColumnName + '", IsPrimaryKey = ' + pkk.ISPK + ')]
    public ' + ColumnType + NullableSign + ' ' + t.ColumnName + ' { get; set; }
'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id ColumnId,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'string'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end ColumnType,
        case 
            when col.is_nullable = 1 and typ.name in ('bigint', 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money', 'numeric', 'real', 'smalldatetime', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'time', 'tinyint', 'uniqueidentifier') 
            then '?' 
            else '' 
        end NullableSign
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id         
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName) 
) t, 
(
                SELECT c.name  AS 'ColumnName', CASE WHEN dd.pk IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END ISPK           
                FROM        sys.columns c
                    JOIN    sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id    
                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT   K.COLUMN_NAME , C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE as pk  
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS K 
                            LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS C
                        ON K.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
                            AND K.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                            AND K.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = C.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
                            AND K.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA            
                        WHERE K.TABLE_NAME = @TableName) as dd
                     ON dd.COLUMN_NAME = c.name
                 WHERE       t.name = @TableName            
            ) pkk
where pkk.ColumnName = t.ColumnName
order by ColumnId

set @Result = @Result  + '
}'

print @Result
```

which makes output needed for full LINQ in C# declaration

```
[System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Table(Name = "HistoricCommand")]
public class DboHistoricCommand
{
    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "HistoricCommandId", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int HistoricCommandId { get; set; }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "PHCloudSoftwareInstanceId", IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int PHCloudSoftwareInstanceId { get; set; }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "CommandType", IsPrimaryKey = false)]
    public int CommandType { get; set; }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "InitiatedDateTime", IsPrimaryKey = false)]
    public DateTime InitiatedDateTime { get; set; }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "CompletedDateTime", IsPrimaryKey = false)]
    public DateTime CompletedDateTime { get; set; }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "WasSuccessful", IsPrimaryKey = false)]
    public bool WasSuccessful { get; set; }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "Message", IsPrimaryKey = false)]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "ResponseData", IsPrimaryKey = false)]
    public string ResponseData { get; set; }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "Message_orig", IsPrimaryKey = false)]
    public string Message_orig { get; set; }

    [System.Data.Linq.Mapping.Column(Name = "Message_XX", IsPrimaryKey = false)]
    public string Message_XX { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I packaged ideas from several SQL based answers here, mainly the root answer by Alex Aza, into **[klassify](http://github.com/tdreid/klassify)**, a console application that generates all the classes for a specified database at once:

---

For example, given a table `Users` that looks like this:

```
+----+------------------+-----------+---------------------+
| Id |       Name       | Username  |        Email        |
+----+------------------+-----------+---------------------+
|  1 | Leanne Graham    | Bret      | Sincere@april.biz   |
|  2 | Ervin Howell     | Antonette | Shanna@melissa.tv   |
|  3 | Clementine Bauch | Samantha  | Nathan@yesenia.net  |
+----+------------------+-----------+---------------------+
```

`klassify` will generate a file called `Users.cs` that looks like this:

```cs
    public class User 
    {
        public int Id {get; set; }
        public string Name { get;set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

It will output one file for every table.  Discard what you don't use.

**Usage**

```
 --out, -o:
        output directory     << defaults to the current directory >>
 --user, -u:
        sql server user id   << required >>
 --password, -p:
        sql server password  << required >>
 --server, -s:
        sql server           << defaults to localhost >>
 --database, -d:
        sql database         << required >>
 --timeout, -t:
        connection timeout   << defaults to 30 >>
 --help, -h:
        show help
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Solution for Oracle DB -> C#

- Single Query
- No Function No Procedure
- Mulitple Table

Added DataAnnotations

- [Key]
- [Required]
- [Table]
- [StringLength]
- [Column]
- Nullable

Query

https://gist.github.com/omansak/f19eefffd2d639ac72a1f4b506d8471a

Output

```
[Table("AGENTS")]
public class Agents
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column("INT_ID", TypeName = "NUMBER(10,0)", Order = 1)]
    public long IntId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    [Column("REFERENCE_CODE", TypeName = "VARCHAR2(15)", Order = 2)]
    public string ReferenceCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("PARENT_INT_ID", TypeName = "NUMBER(10,0)", Order = 3)]
    public long ParentIntId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Column("TITLE", TypeName = "VARCHAR2(200)", Order = 4)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("START_DATE", TypeName = "DATE", Order = 5)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("END_DATE", TypeName = "DATE", Order = 6)]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    [Column("AGENT_TYPE", TypeName = "VARCHAR2(1)", Order = 7)]
    public string AgentType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("CREATE_DATE", TypeName = "DATE", Order = 8)]
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(32)]
    [Column("CREATE_USER", TypeName = "VARCHAR2(32)", Order = 9)]
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Column("RESPONSIBLE_CONTACT", TypeName = "VARCHAR2(200)", Order = 10)]
    public string ResponsibleContact { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Column("RESPONSIBLE_TITLE", TypeName = "VARCHAR2(100)", Order = 11)]
    public string ResponsibleTitle { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Column("AGENCY_PLATE_NO", TypeName = "VARCHAR2(100)", Order = 12)]
    public string AgencyPlateNo { get; set; }
    [Column("AGENCY_COVER_AMOUNT", TypeName = "NUMBER(24,2)", Order = 13)]
    public double? AgencyCoverAmount { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Column("MERSIS_NO", TypeName = "VARCHAR2(100)", Order = 14)]
    public string MersisNo { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Column("TECH_PERSONEL_NO", TypeName = "VARCHAR2(100)", Order = 15)]
    public string TechPersonelNo { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Column("TECH_PERSONEL_NAME", TypeName = "VARCHAR2(100)", Order = 16)]
    public string TechPersonelName { get; set; }
    [Column("COVER_END_DATE", TypeName = "DATE", Order = 17)]
    public DateTime? CoverEndDate { get; set; }
    [Column("BRANCH_NUMBER", TypeName = "NUMBER(10,0)", Order = 18)]
    public long? BranchNumber { get; set; }
    [Column("ACTION_NUMBER", TypeName = "NUMBER(10,0)", Order = 19)]
    public long? ActionNumber { get; set; }
    [Column("CLUB_PARTICIPATION_COUNT", TypeName = "NUMBER(10,0)", Order = 20)]
    public long? ClubParticipationCount { get; set; }
    [Column("AGENCY_CONTRACT_DATE", TypeName = "DATE", Order = 21)]
    public DateTime? AgencyContractDate { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    [Column("KEP_ADDRESS", TypeName = "VARCHAR2(200)", Order = 22)]
    public string KepAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: PS : If your table has more than one primary key you have to set PKs with fluent API

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is EF, Reverse Engineer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj593170

Answer (score 0):

I like to setup my classes with private local members and public accessors / mutators.
So I've modified Alex's script above to do that as well for anyone that is intersted.

```
declare @TableName sysname = 'TABLE_NAME'
declare @result varchar(max) = 'public class ' + @TableName + '
{'

SET @result = @result + 
'
    public ' + @TableName + '()
    {}
';

select @result = @result + '
    private ' + ColumnType + ' ' + ' m_' + stuff(replace(ColumnName, '_', ''), 1, 1, lower(left(ColumnName, 1))) + ';'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'char'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end ColumnType
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t
order by column_id

SET @result = @result + '
'

select @result = @result + '
    public ' + ColumnType + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get { return m_' + stuff(replace(ColumnName, '_', ''), 1, 1, lower(left(ColumnName, 1))) + ';} set {m_' + stuff(replace(ColumnName, '_', ''), 1, 1, lower(left(ColumnName, 1))) + ' = value;} }' from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'char'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end ColumnType
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t
order by column_id

set @result = @result  + '
}'

print @result
```

Answer (score 0):

A small addition to the solutions before:
`object_id(@TableName)` works only if you are in the default schema.

```
(Select id from sysobjects where name = @TableName)
```

works in any schema provided @tableName is unique.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's useful to anyone else, working on a Code-First approach using attribute mappings, I wanted something that just left me needing to bind an entity in the object model.  So thanks to Carnotaurus' answer, I extended it as per their own suggestion and made a couple of tweaks.

This relies therefore on this solution comprising TWO parts, both of which are SQL Scalar-Valued functions:

> 1. An 'Initial Caps' function (taken from:
>      https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8a58dbe1-7a4b-4287-afdc-bfecb4e69b23/similar-to-initcap-in-sql-server-tsql
>      and slightly modified to meet my needs)

```
ALTER function [dbo].[ProperCase] (@cStringToProper varchar(8000))
returns varchar(8000)
as
begin
   declare  @Position int
    select @cStringToProper = stuff(lower(@cStringToProper) , 1 , 1 , upper(left(@cStringToProper , 1)))
        , @Position = patindex('%[^a-zA-Z][a-z]%' , @cStringToProper collate Latin1_General_Bin)

   while @Position > 0
         select @cStringToProper = stuff(@cStringToProper , @Position , 2 , upper(substring(@cStringToProper , @Position , 2)))
              , @Position = patindex('%[^a-zA-Z][a-z]%' , @cStringToProper collate Latin1_General_Bin)

  select @cStringToProper = replace(@cStringToProper, '_','')

   return @cStringToProper
end
```

> 2. The output function itself, which extends Carnotaurus' solution by:
>
>    - Correctly outputting newline characters
>    - Performing some basic tabulation
>    - Writing out an appropriate a [Table] mapping (as suggested)
>    - Writing out an appropriate [Column] mapping, including the type name (as suggested)
>    - Allowing the Entity name to differ from the name of the table
>    - Fixes the limitation of the Print @Result truncating when you have tables with a large number of columns

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetEntityObject] (@NameSpace NVARCHAR(MAX), @TableName NVARCHAR(MAX), @EntityName NVARCHAR(MAX))  RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS BEGIN

DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @result = @result + 'using System;' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) 

IF (@NameSpace IS NOT NULL)  BEGIN
    SET @result = @result + 'namespace ' + @NameSpace  + CHAR(13) + '{' + CHAR(13)  END

SET @result = @result + '[Table(name: ' + CHAR(34) + @TableName + CHAR(34) + ')]' + CHAR(13) SET @result = @result + 'public class ' + @EntityName + CHAR(13) + '{' + CHAR(13) 

SET @result = @result + '#region Instance Properties' + CHAR(13)  

SELECT @result = @result + CHAR(13)     + '[Column(name: ' + CHAR(34) + OriginalColumnName + CHAR(34) + ', TypeName = ' + CHAR(34) + DataType
+ CHAR(34) + ')]' + CHAR(13)
    + 'public ' + ColumnType + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get; set; } ' + CHAR(13)  FROM (
    SELECT dbo.ProperCase (c.COLUMN_NAME)   AS ColumnName 
        , CASE c.DATA_TYPE   
            WHEN 'bigint' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int64?' ELSE 'Int64' END
            WHEN 'binary' THEN 'Byte[]'
            WHEN 'bit' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Boolean?' ELSE 'Boolean' END            
            WHEN 'char' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'date' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                        
            WHEN 'datetime' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                        
            WHEN 'datetime2' THEN  
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                        
            WHEN 'datetimeoffset' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTimeOffset?' ELSE 'DateTimeOffset' END                                    
            WHEN 'decimal' THEN  
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                    
            WHEN 'float' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Single?' ELSE 'Single' END                                    
            WHEN 'image' THEN 'Byte[]'
            WHEN 'int' THEN  
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int32?' ELSE 'Int32' END
            WHEN 'money' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                                
            WHEN 'nchar' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'ntext' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'numeric' THEN
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                                            
            WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'real' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Double?' ELSE 'Double' END                                                                        
            WHEN 'smalldatetime' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                                    
            WHEN 'smallint' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int16?' ELSE 'Int16'END            
            WHEN 'smallmoney' THEN  
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                                                        
            WHEN 'text' THEN 'String'
            WHEN 'time' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'TimeSpan?' ELSE 'TimeSpan' END                                         
            WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                                    
            WHEN 'tinyint' THEN 
                CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                    WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Byte?' ELSE 'Byte' END                                                
            WHEN 'uniqueidentifier' THEN 'Guid'
            WHEN 'varbinary' THEN 'Byte[]'
            WHEN 'varchar' THEN 'String'
            ELSE 'Object'
        END AS ColumnType
        , c.ORDINAL_POSITION        , c.COLUMN_NAME as OriginalColumnName       ,c.DATA_TYPE as DataType

FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WHERE   c.TABLE_NAME = @TableName) t ORDER BY t.ORDINAL_POSITION

SET @result = @result + CHAR(13) + '#endregion Instance Properties' + CHAR(13)  

SET @result = @result  + '}' + CHAR(13)

IF (@TableName IS NOT NULL)  BEGIN
    SET @result = @result + CHAR(13) + '}'  END

return @result END
```

Usage from within MS SQL Management Studio:

> SELECT dbo.GetEntityObject('MyNameSpace', 'MyTableName', 'MyEntityName')

will result in a column value you can copy and paste into Visual Studio.

If it helps anyone, then great!

Comment: I stopped short of adding in [Key] attributes because it's easy enough to add that manually.  Also you may get an error along the lines of failing to map Real to Edm.Double[Nullable=True,DefaultValue=].  If this is the case, try modifying either the relevant property, or the function to map Real, to Single.

Answer (score 0):

Java class Generation

```
declare @TableName varchar(max) = 'Restaurants'
declare @Templete varchar(max) = ' 
     public @ColumnType @ColumnName ; // @ColumnDesc  
     public @ColumnType get@ColumnName()
     {
        return this.@ColumnName;
     }
     public void set@ColumnName(@ColumnType @ColumnName)
     {
        this.@ColumnName=@ColumnName;
     }

     '
declare @before varchar(max)='public class  @TableName  
{'
   
declare @after varchar(max)='
}'



declare @result varchar(max)

set @before =replace(@before,'@TableName',@TableName)

set @result=@before

select @result = @result 
+ replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@Templete,'@ColumnType',ColumnType) ,'@ColumnName',ColumnName) ,'@ColumnDesc',ColumnDesc),'@ISPK',ISPK),'@max_length',max_length)

from  
(
    select 
    column_id,
    replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
    typ.name as sqltype,
    typ.max_length,
    is_identity,
    pkk.ISPK, 
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'String'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'char'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'String'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'String'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        END + CASE WHEN col.is_nullable=1 AND typ.name NOT IN ('binary', 'varbinary', 'image', 'text', 'ntext', 'varchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'nchar') THEN '?' ELSE '' END ColumnType,
      isnull(colDesc.colDesc,'') AS ColumnDesc 
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
            left join
            (
                SELECT c.name  AS 'ColumnName', CASE WHEN dd.pk IS NULL THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END ISPK           
                FROM        sys.columns c
                    JOIN    sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id    
                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT   K.COLUMN_NAME , C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE as pk  
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS K 
                            LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS C
                        ON K.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
                            AND K.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                            AND K.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = C.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
                            AND K.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA            
                        WHERE K.TABLE_NAME = @TableName) as dd
                     ON dd.COLUMN_NAME = c.name
                 WHERE       t.name = @TableName       
            ) pkk  on ColumnName=col.name

    OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 CAST(value AS NVARCHAR(max)) AS colDesc
    FROM
       sys.extended_properties
    WHERE
       major_id = col.object_id
       AND
       minor_id = COLUMNPROPERTY(major_id, col.name, 'ColumnId')
    ) colDesc      
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)

    ) t

    set @result=@result+@after

    select @result
    --print @result
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate from Postgres DB

`DO $$
DECLARE v_tabela varchar;
DECLARE v_cursor_colunas record;
DECLARE v_nome_coluna varchar;
DECLARE v_classe VARCHAR;
DECLARE v_tipo VARCHAR;
DECLARE v_schema_name VARCHAR;
BEGIN
v_schema_name := 'my-schema';
v_tabela := 'my-table';
select table_name INTO v_tabela from information_schema.tables where table_schema = v_schema_name
and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
and table_name = v_tabela;
v_classe := E'\r\n' || 'public class ' || v_tabela || ' {' ||  E'\r\n';
FOR v_cursor_colunas IN
SELECT column_name as coluna, is_nullable as isnull, data_type as tipo, character_maximum_length as tamanho
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = v_schema_name
AND table_name   = v_tabela
LOOP

IF v_cursor_colunas.tipo='character varying' THEN
v_tipo:= 'string';
ELSIF v_cursor_colunas.tipo='character' and v_cursor_colunas.tamanho=1 THEN
v_tipo:= 'char';
ELSIF v_cursor_colunas.tipo='character' and v_cursor_colunas.tamanho<>1 THEN
v_tipo:= 'string';
ELSIF v_cursor_colunas.tipo like 'timestamp%' THEN
v_tipo:= 'DateTime';
IF v_cursor_colunas.isnull='YES' then
v_tipo:= 'DateTime?';
END IF;
ELSIF v_cursor_colunas.tipo='boolean' THEN
v_tipo:= 'bool';
IF v_cursor_colunas.isnull='YES' then
v_tipo:= 'bool?';
END IF;
ELSIF v_cursor_colunas.tipo='integer' THEN
v_tipo:= 'int';
IF v_cursor_colunas.isnull='YES' then
v_tipo:= 'int?';
END IF;
ELSIF v_cursor_colunas.tipo='numeric' THEN
v_tipo:= 'double';
IF v_cursor_colunas.isnull='YES' then
v_tipo:= 'double?';
END IF;
ELSIF v_cursor_colunas.tipo='text' THEN
v_tipo:= 'string';
ELSE
v_tipo:= 'another';
END IF;

v_nome_coluna := v_cursor_colunas.coluna;
v_classe := v_classe || 'public ' || v_tipo || ' ' || v_cursor_colunas.coluna || ' { get; set; }' || E'\r\n';

END LOOP;`

v_classe := v_classe || E'\r\n' || '}';
RAISE NOTICE '%' , v_classe;
END $$;

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution for Postgres DB -> C#

- Compatible with [NpgSQL](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html)
- Added [DataAnnotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=net-5.0)

```
    SELECT
            CASE 
                WHEN c.is_nullable ='NO'  THEN '[Required]'||chr(10)
                ELSE '' END
            ||CASE 
                WHEN c.data_type = 'character varying' THEN format('[StringLength(%s)]',c.character_maximum_length)||chr(10)
                ELSE '' END
            ||'public '
            ||CASE 
                WHEN c.data_type = 'integer' THEN 'int'
                WHEN c.data_type = 'boolean' THEN 'bool'
                WHEN c.data_type = 'double precision' THEN 'double'
                WHEN c.data_type = 'uuid' THEN 'Guid'
                WHEN c.data_type = 'character varying' THEN 'string'
                WHEN c.data_type = 'timestamp without time zone' THEN 'DateTime'    
                WHEN c.data_type = 'bigint' THEN 'long'   
                WHEN c.data_type = 'bytea' THEN 'byte[]'    
            ELSE 'object' END
            ||CASE
                WHEN c.is_nullable='YES' AND NOT  c.data_type = 'character varying' THEN '? '
                ELSE ' ' END
            ||c.column_name||' {get;set;}'
            ,c.*
    FROM information_schema."columns" c
    WHERE 1=1
    AND c.table_name='YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with node.js and it's working fine for me.

- It will create model files for you. You can create multiple model files

Pre requisite: [install node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

> **Require changes:**

- Create index.js file in your workspace
- Add your tables object in "allTable" (Highlighted in screenshot)
- Change folder path (I have given my system path)
- Execute command node index.js

> node index.js

[image]

> Output

[image]

```js
const fs = require('fs/promises');

async function convertToDataType(dataArray, fileName) {
    let count = 0;
    let tempArray = [];
    var dataTypeArray = [
        {
            "key": "bigint",
            "value": "long"
        },
        {
            "key": "binary",
            "value": "byte[]"
        },
        {
            "key": "bit",
            "value": "bool"
        },
        {
            "key": "char",
            "value": "string"
        },
        {
            "key": "date",
            "value": "DateTime"
        },
        {
            "key": "datetime",
            "value": "DateTime"
        },
        {
            "key": "datetime2",
            "value": "DateTime"
        },
        {
            "key": "datetimeoffset",
            "value": "DateTimeOffset"
        },
        {
            "key": "decimal",
            "value": "decimal"
        },
        {
            "key": "float",
            "value": "double"
        },
        {
            "key": "image",
            "value": "byte[]"
        },
        {
            "key": "int",
            "value": "int"
        },
        {
            "key": "money",
            "value": "decimal"
        },
        {
            "key": "nchar",
            "value": "string"
        },
        {
            "key": "ntext",
            "value": "string"
        },
        {
            "key": "numeric",
            "value": "decimal"
        },
        {
            "key": "nvarchar",
            "value": "string"
        },
        {
            "key": "real",
            "value": "float"
        },
        {
            "key": "smalldatetime",
            "value": "DateTime"
        },
        {
            "key": "smallint",
            "value": "short"
        },
        {
            "key": "smallmoney",
            "value": "decimal"
        },
        {
            "key": "text",
            "value": "string"
        },
        {
            "key": "time",
            "value": "TimeSpan"
        },
        {
            "key": "timestamp",
            "value": "long"
        },
        {
            "key": "tinyint",
            "value": "byte"
        },
        {
            "key": "uniqueidentifier",
            "value": "Guid"
        },
        {
            "key": "varbinary",
            "value": "byte[]"
        },
        {
            "key": "varchar",
            "value": "string"
        }
    ]
    dataArray.map(i => {
        let objDataType = '';
        objDataType = dataTypeArray.filter(data => data.key == i.split(' ')[1].replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))[0].value;

        if (objDataType == '') {
            count++;
        }

        let isNull = i.includes('NULL') && !(i.includes('varchar') || i.includes('bit')) ? '?' : '';
        isNull = i.includes('NOT NULL') ? '' : isNull;
        const varValue = i.split(' ')[0].replace('[', '').replace(']', '');

        if (count != 0) {
            console.warn(`\n\n\n ======> Error:: Check data type is missing. Datatype => ${i.split(' ')[1]} Object Name: ${fileName} \n\n\n`);
        } else {
            tempArray.push(`public ${objDataType}${isNull} ${varValue} { get; set; }`);
        }
    });
    return tempArray;
}

async function convertToModel() {
    try {
        let allTable = {
            EmployeeAllowancesHistory: [
                "[EmployeeAllowanceHistoryID] [int] NOT NULL",
                "[EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL",
                "[AllowanceID] [int] NOT NULL",
                "[DateID] [int] NULL",
                "[Amount] [numeric] NOT NULL",
                "[Insured] [bit] NULL",
                "[ChangeDate] [datetime] NOT NULL",
                "[NewAmount] [numeric] NULL"
            ], Cities: [
                "[CityID] [int] NOT NULL",
                "[CityCode] [varchar] NOT NULL",
                "[CityNameAr] [varchar] NULL",
                "[CityNameEn] [varchar] NULL",
                "[InKSA] [bit] NOT NULL",
                "[HighClass] [bit] NOT NULL",
                "[TravelDays] [int] NULL"
            ], Regions: [
                "[RegionID] [int] NOT NULL",
                "[RegionCode] [nvarchar] NULL",
                "[RegionNameEn] [nvarchar] NULL",
                "[RegionNameAr] [nvarchar] NULL",
                "[CityID] [int] NULL"
            ]
        }
        for (var file in allTable) {
            const tableObject = await convertToDataType(allTable[file], file);
            let tempContent = "[key]";
            tableObject.map(obj => {
                tempContent = `${tempContent}
        ${obj}`
            });
            const content = `using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Core.Entities
{
    public class ${file}
    {
        ${tempContent}
    }
}`
            fs.writeFile(`/model_files/${file}.cs`, content);
        }
        console.log('Created successfully...');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

convertToModel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified the query with Data Annotation.

```
declare @TableName sysname  = 'Table Name' --Table Name
DECLARE @RequiredAnno BIT   =1  -- Enable Required Data Annotation ([Required])
DECLARE @DataTypeAnno BIT   =1  -- Enable column TypeName Data Annotation ([Column(TypeName = "numeric(10, 0)")])
DECLARE @MaxLengthAnno BIT  =1  -- Enable MaxLength Data Annotation ([Column(TypeName = "numeric(10, 0)")])

-----------------SQL Script-------------------------------
DECLARE @NewLine VARCHAR(10)='
    '
declare @Result varchar(max) = 'public class ' + @TableName + '
{'

select @Result = @Result +CASE WHEN @RequiredAnno=1 then @NewLine ELSE '' END +RequiredAnno +CASE WHEN @DataTypeAnno=1 then @NewLine ELSE '' END + DataTypeAnno +CASE WHEN @MaxLengthAnno=1 then @NewLine ELSE '' END + MaxLngthAnno +'
    public ' + ColumnType + NullableSign + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get; set; }
'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id ColumnId,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'double'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'string'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'float'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'long'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end ColumnType,
        case 
            when col.is_nullable = 1 and typ.name in ('bigint', 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money', 'numeric', 'real', 'smalldatetime', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'time', 'tinyint', 'uniqueidentifier') 
                then '?' 
            else '' 
        end NullableSign,
        case 
            WHEN @RequiredAnno=0    
                THEN ''
            when col.is_nullable = 1  
                then '' 
            else '[Required]' 
        end RequiredAnno,
        case 
            WHEN @DataTypeAnno=0
                THEN ''
            when typ.name in ('bigint', 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money',  'real', 'smalldatetime', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'time', 'tinyint', 'uniqueidentifier') 
                then '[Column(TypeName = "' + UPPER(typ.name) +'")]'
            when col.precision >0 OR col.scale > 0 
                then '[Column(TypeName = "' + UPPER(typ.name) +'('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,col.precision) +','+  CONVERT(VARCHAR,col.scale) +')")]'
            else '[Column(TypeName = "' + UPPER(typ.name) +'('+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,col.max_length)+ ')")]'
            end DataTypeAnno,
        case 
            WHEN @MaxLengthAnno=0
                THEN ''
            WHEN typ.name in ('char','varbinary','varchar','nvarchar','nchar','ntext','text')   
                THEN '[MaxLength('+CONVERT(VARCHAR,col.max_length) +')]'
            else '' 
        end MaxLngthAnno
            
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t
order by ColumnId

set @Result = @Result  + '
}'

print @Result
```

Answer (score -4):

You just did, as long as your table contains two columns and is called something like 'tblPeople'.

You can always write your own SQL wrappers. I actually prefer to do it that way, I HATE generated code, in any fashion.

Maybe create a `DAL` class, and have a method called `GetPerson(int id)`, that queries the database for that person, and then creates your `Person` object from the result set.