# Auto generate models classes in mvc from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class, model

I heard that people use entity framework to generate model related classes from database. Suppose if I do not want to use entity framework as data access layer rather I want to use MS data application block so then how can I auto generate models classes in MVC from database instead of writing model related classes manually. Please guide me with all the possible ways. Thanks

Comment: You should look up Linq To SQL and how to use the drag and drop UI that goes with it. Here's a tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22000/LINQ-to-SQL

Comment: If you can generate xsd files from your database then you can use xsd.exe to generate classes from xsd files.

Comment: I think you're looking for this tool https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d

Answer (score 9):

I know this is an old question but for a quick and easy class I use this in SMS. It adds the 'required' and 'string-length' data annotations I routinely use.

[Based upon this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873170/generate-class-from-database-table)

```
    DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX) = 'tablename' -- Replace 'tablename' with your table name
    DECLARE @NameSpace VARCHAR(MAX) = 'namespace' -- Replace 'namespace' with your class namespace
    DECLARE @TableSchema VARCHAR(MAX) = 'dbo' -- Replace 'dbo' with your schema name
    DECLARE @result varchar(max) = ''

    SET @result = @result + 'using System;' + CHAR(13)
    SET @result = @result + 'using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(13) 

    IF (@TableSchema IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        SET @result = @result + 'namespace ' + @NameSpace  + CHAR(13) + '{' + CHAR(13) 
    END

    SET @result = @result + 'public class ' + @TableName + CHAR(13) + '{' + CHAR(13) 

    SET @result = @result + '#region Instance Properties' + CHAR(13)  

    SELECT @result = @result + CHAR(13)     
        + ' [Display(Name = "' + ColumnName + '")] ' + CHAR(13) 
        + CASE bRequired WHEN 'NO' 
        THEN 
        CASE WHEN Len(MaxLen) > 0 THEN ' [Required, StringLength(' + MaxLen + ')]' + CHAR(13) ELSE ' [Required] ' + CHAR(13)  END   
        ELSE
        CASE WHEN Len(MaxLen) > 0 THEN ' [StringLength(' + MaxLen + ')]' + CHAR(13) ELSE '' END  
        END
        + ' public ' + ColumnType + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get; set; } ' + CHAR(13) 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  c.COLUMN_NAME   AS ColumnName 
            , CASE c.DATA_TYPE   
                WHEN 'bigint' THEN
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int64?' ELSE 'Int64' END
                WHEN 'binary' THEN 'Byte[]'
                WHEN 'bit' THEN 
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Boolean?' ELSE 'Boolean' END            
                WHEN 'char' THEN 'String'
                WHEN 'date' THEN
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                        
                WHEN 'datetime' THEN
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                        
                WHEN 'datetime2' THEN  
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                        
                WHEN 'datetimeoffset' THEN 
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTimeOffset?' ELSE 'DateTimeOffset' END                                    
                WHEN 'decimal' THEN  
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                    
                WHEN 'float' THEN 
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Single?' ELSE 'Single' END                                    
                WHEN 'image' THEN 'Byte[]'
                WHEN 'int' THEN  
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int32?' ELSE 'Int32' END
                WHEN 'money' THEN
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                                
                WHEN 'nchar' THEN 'String'
                WHEN 'ntext' THEN 'String'
                WHEN 'numeric' THEN
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                                            
                WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN 'String'
                WHEN 'real' THEN 
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Double?' ELSE 'Double' END                                                                        
                WHEN 'smalldatetime' THEN 
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                                    
                WHEN 'smallint' THEN 
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Int16?' ELSE 'Int16'END            
                WHEN 'smallmoney' THEN  
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Decimal?' ELSE 'Decimal' END                                                                        
                WHEN 'text' THEN 'String'
                WHEN 'time' THEN 
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'TimeSpan?' ELSE 'TimeSpan' END                                                                                    
                WHEN 'timestamp' THEN 
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'DateTime?' ELSE 'DateTime' END                                    
                WHEN 'tinyint' THEN 
                    CASE C.IS_NULLABLE
                        WHEN 'YES' THEN 'Byte?' ELSE 'Byte' END                                                
                WHEN 'uniqueidentifier' THEN 'Guid'
                WHEN 'varbinary' THEN 'Byte[]'
                WHEN 'varchar' THEN 'String'
                ELSE 'Object'
            END AS ColumnType,
                c.IS_NULLABLE AS bRequired,
                CASE c.DATA_TYPE             
                WHEN 'char' THEN  CONVERT(varchar(10),c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)
                WHEN 'nchar' THEN  CONVERT(varchar(10),c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)
                WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN  CONVERT(varchar(10),c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)
                WHEN 'varchar' THEN  CONVERT(varchar(10),c.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH)
                ELSE ''
            END AS MaxLen,
            c.ORDINAL_POSITION 
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    WHERE   c.TABLE_NAME = @TableName and ISNULL(@TableSchema, c.TABLE_SCHEMA) = c.TABLE_SCHEMA  
    ) t
    ORDER BY t.ORDINAL_POSITION

    SET @result = @result + CHAR(13) + '#endregion Instance Properties' + CHAR(13)  

    SET @result = @result  + '}' + CHAR(13)

    IF (@TableSchema IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN
        SET @result = @result + CHAR(13) + '}' 
    END

    PRINT @result
```

Answer (score 6):

Good way to do it is to use ADO.NET Entity Data Model:
In Visual Studio right click on your project -> "Add" -> "New Item" -> "Data" -> "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" -> "Generate from database" -> choose or create connection -> choose tables -> expand created *.tt file group -> You get it :-)

Comment: i said that i will not use  entity framework rather i want to use MSDAAB instead then why you are saying to use EF?

Comment: Sorry if it doesn't work for you. But for one-use it's the best way. After classes generation you don't need to use EF.

Comment: I've done this. But my class doesn't have a constructor. In your case, did it have a constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Run the below script in SqlServerManagementStudio, For the required table you will get the result...

```
    declare @TableName sysname = 'tblQuotations'
declare @Result varchar(max) = 'public class ' + @TableName + '
{'

select @Result = @Result + '
    public ' + ColumnType + NullableSign + ' ' + ColumnName + ' { get; set; }
'
from
(
    select 
        replace(col.name, ' ', '_') ColumnName,
        column_id ColumnId,
        case typ.name 
            when 'bigint' then 'long'
            when 'binary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'bit' then 'bool'
            when 'char' then 'string'
            when 'date' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetime2' then 'DateTime'
            when 'datetimeoffset' then 'DateTimeOffset'
            when 'decimal' then 'decimal'
            when 'float' then 'float'
            when 'image' then 'byte[]'
            when 'int' then 'int'
            when 'money' then 'decimal'
            when 'nchar' then 'string'
            when 'ntext' then 'string'
            when 'numeric' then 'decimal'
            when 'nvarchar' then 'string'
            when 'real' then 'double'
            when 'smalldatetime' then 'DateTime'
            when 'smallint' then 'short'
            when 'smallmoney' then 'decimal'
            when 'text' then 'string'
            when 'time' then 'TimeSpan'
            when 'timestamp' then 'DateTime'
            when 'tinyint' then 'byte'
            when 'uniqueidentifier' then 'Guid'
            when 'varbinary' then 'byte[]'
            when 'varchar' then 'string'
            else 'UNKNOWN_' + typ.name
        end ColumnType,
        case 
            when col.is_nullable = 1 and typ.name in ('bigint', 'bit', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime2', 'datetimeoffset', 'decimal', 'float', 'int', 'money', 'numeric', 'real', 'smalldatetime', 'smallint', 'smallmoney', 'time', 'tinyint', 'uniqueidentifier') 
            then '?' 
            else '' 
        end NullableSign
    from sys.columns col
        join sys.types typ on
            col.system_type_id = typ.system_type_id AND col.user_type_id = typ.user_type_id
    where object_id = object_id(@TableName)
) t
order by ColumnId

set @Result = @Result  + '
}'

print @Result
```

Comment: This answer seems to be a near duplicate of several answers from [Generate class from database table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5873170/3744182) including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5873231/3744182) by [Alex Aza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/732945/alex-aza) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43357818/3744182) from [Sasha Bond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464815/sasha-bond), though there are differences in the `case typ.name` statement.

Comment: Comparing those answers with yours, your code does `when 'float' then 'float'` and `when 'nchar' then 'string'` which Sasha Bond's answer also does.  Might you please [edit] your question to explain a little why you chose that version to model your answer (if you did) and how this code works?

Comment: And finally, when you copy and modify posts written by other stack overflow contributors, you must credit them as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing: 1)  Provide a link to the original page or answer. 2) Quote only the relevant portion. 3) Provide the name of the original author.  Please [edit] your question to add the required attribution(s) if any.