# Fastest way to assign properties to class from datarow C#

Tags: c#, class, properties, automation

Right now Im working in a big project, So theres a lot of data and tables going around.

For best practices Im creating a class for every table and object

Its goes like this:

```
public class Employee
{
    private String Name;
    public String Name
    {
        get
        {
            return Name;
        }
        set
        {
            Name = value;
        }
    }

    public Employee(int EmployeeID) 
    {
        /*
         GET DATA ROW AND ASSIGN IT TO EVERY PROPERTIE
         * 
         * Name = row("name")
         * AND DO THIS FOR EVERY PROPERTIE!
         * 
         */
    }
}
```

So whats happening here is that I have to assign every propertie from a query in the class constructor.

But imagine a table with like 50+ columns, I have to do this 50+ times and this takes a lot of time.

Theres a way to automate this automate the creation of the 50+ properties and the asignation of the 50+ properties in the class withouth taking a lot of time.

**I just wanna find a way to create a class automating the properties assignation from a datarow instead of writting all the columns string to the properties. Something like Entityt Framework but done by me.**

Greeting and thanks

Comment: That code wouldn't even compile, as you're declaring two members with the same name. (It looks like you should just use automatic properties.) Do you have *evidence* that setting these properties is actually a bottleneck? Assuming these are coming from a database, the database access is going to *vastly* outweigh the time taken for trivial assignments.

Comment: I wrote the snippet fast hehe. I just wanna find a way to create a class automating the properties assignation from a datarow instead of writting all the columns string to the properties. Something like Entityt Framework but done by me...

Comment: So are you saying the problem isn't execution-time performance, but the annoyance of writing the code? If so, please clarify your post - it gives the impression of being about performance at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Jon :) I will..

Answer (score 0):

There are heaps of examples online to make C# classes from dB tables & stored procedures, research that and POCO's, eg:

[Generate class from database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873170/generate-class-from-database-table)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8397/C-Code-Generator-for-Stored-Procedures

You're not the first to encounter this, best to do a quick google next time.

Answer (score 0):

you should use better entity framework code first approach, it works even if your database is already created.

use a tool to generate the class model, and create a context like:

```
  public class MyContext : DbContext
  {
      public MyContext (){}
       public DbSet<MyModel> MyModel { get; set; }
  }
```