# is there any app to read SQL table and make or convert to .NET class (Repository class, Model class, ...)

Tags: sql, .net, model, repository

is there any app to read SQL table and make or convert to .NET class (Repository class, Model class, ...)?

is there any online site, or program ?

Comment: Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873170/generate-class-from-database-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you aim to use EF you can do this in Visual Studio by using the "ADO.NET Entity Data Model"-template. Simply right click on a project and add a new item. Then select Data and ADO.NET Entity Data Model.

[image]

Then select the DB-first option.

[image]

Choose which items (tables, views etc) you want. Then finish the wizard and Visual Studio will create models and context for the table enteties. In the image below I've used the Northwind DB.

You can read more about the designer here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc716685(v=vs.100).aspx

[image]