# Generate C# class from SQL Server table without Store Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, oop

Is there any way to generate a class for table in SQL Server without adding table in project with ADO.net Entity Framework?

[image]

```
public class Approval
{
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long? FormId { get; set; }
        public long? DesignationId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you can use database first approach which will create a diagram and then all classes

Comment: What problem are you *actually* trying to solve? You have already created a class to model the table you show.

Comment: I am using store procedure to get data and in razor view i want to refer a class of store procedure like
@model Brass.Models.EmployeeClass
so i want a easy way to generate class dont want to use long procedure like code first approch

Comment: @MaxVernon: Does Dapper have a tool to create a POCO type from a table or query?  I had a tool I wrote in a previous job (that extracted metadata from a Data Reader), but, alas, I don't work there anymore.

Comment: I'm curious about this too, but for stored procedures. I'd like to somehow return the column data types from a SP and turn it into a POCO.

Comment: @Flydog57 - actually I don't think it does.  I'll remove my comment.

Comment: Look here: https://gist.github.com/halityurttas/17e36d2fa047b925ccef7940d451083e

Comment: Copy 1 Row of output (with header) and paste here to [Generate Class from CSV](https://toolslick.com/generation/code/class-from-csv)

Comment: Open Package Manager Console and type this: `Scaffold-DbContext "Server=servername.com;Database=My_Db;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir "Models/Entities" -DataAnnotations -Tables Approval`. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=vs.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This online tool generates a class from SQL table. Class is based on the `CREATE TABLE` script in `MS-SQL`, `ORACLE`, `MYSQL`, `POSTGRESQL` and `SQLite`  databases, to a class in C# and other programming languages.

https://codverter.com/src/sqltoclass

[image]

Comment: Great we find I was using a .net desktop app but it always froze i love these online tools nice work if it is use.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't feel like typing out a really long class. This tool saved me 10 min!

Comment: If you do not want to use online tool ,use store procedure in following post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873170/generate-class-from-database-table

Comment: @WaqasNawazWarraich Thank you for the link. BTW, from a security point of view, All the data entered to the editors is interpreted and converted only on the client-side (using Angular and Typescript) and never sent back to the server (full disclosure - I am the developer of this tool).

Comment: @jonathana no doubt your tool is very helpful and user friendly, Well done

Comment: bigint nullable columns are not generated with "?"

Comment: Great tool. Added to my favorites.

Comment: What a great tool. Thank you for sharing and thank you to the devs!

Answer (score 30):

If you want to use Entity Framework you should consider to use [Database First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first) approach.

Other simple and fast way to import a Sql Server scheme to a class in VS is this:

1. Make a `select` as json query:

   ```sql
   SELECT * FROM Approval 
   FOR JSON AUTO
   ```
2. Copy one row from the result in your clipboard:

   ```
   [
     {"Id":1, "FormId":10, "DesignationId":100, "CreatedOn":"2000-01-01T00:00:00"},
     {"Id":2, "FormId":20, "DesignationId":200, "CreatedOn":"2000-01-01T00:00:00"}
   ]
   ```
3. Paste in Visual Studio: `Edit` > `Paste Special` > `Paste JSON As Classes`

   [image: Paste JSON as Classes]

Comment: JSON is only supported in MSSQL 2016+.  But Paste as XML works great in MSSQL 2008+.

Comment: am on 2019 have they removed this now ?.

Comment: @rogue39nin it's still under Edit in VS2019, but not there if you "right-click".

Comment: This works great but it doesn't work until you have data. I just built the table and I don't want to go through the trouble of adding data.

Answer (score 11):

For tables, stored procedures, etc., when you have many POCO to generate:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/892233/POCO-Generator

[image: POCO generator]

or for simple single queries:

https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/12/11/sqlqueryresults-code-generation.aspx

[image: Simple POCO generator]

Comment: can be quite buggy and often crash.