# C# - Generate POCO from Oracle DB

Tags: c#, oracle, model

I wanna create a DB Model from my Database. I just need the plain classes, no validation or connection stuff. For each table and view I want to create a class looking like this:

```
public class TableName
{
   public string col1 {get; set;}
   public int col2 {get; set;}
}
```

I need to have this structure for all my tables and views. The DbScaffold doesnt work with the newest Oracle DB. Does somebody have any suggestions? Because there has to be a tool which generates the classes but I simply cant find it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225503/generate-c-sharp-class-from-sql-server-table   references this online tool  https://codverter.com/src/sqltoclass .   If your number of tables and views is large you should look at something more repeatable and less manual.

Comment: Entity Framework https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/CodeFirst/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework / Entity Framework Core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/CodeFirst/index.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDZXJYLUC7I