# Typescript definitions for SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, typescript, stored-procedures

I am using [SQL Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql)  and interact with the database exclusively through stored procedures (no SQL statements, tables, etc). I have access to the T-SQL source code, a `.dacpac`, and the database itself.

Are there any existing tools/ORM's that can generate TypeScript type definitions (*.d.ts files) for the stored procedures?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873170/generate-class-from-database-table) question is related, but different language and for tables instead of stored procedures

Comment: Everything about this question terrifies me.

Comment: What do you mean by "generate types for stored procedures"? Your question is not clear. And no idea what that link has to do with your question at all.

Comment: @IanKemp agreed, but its where I'm at

Comment: Are you asking what SQL Server metadata you can use to write your own code generators, or asking whether there are any Object-Relational Maping (ORM) solutions for Typescript?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft the second, edited the question accordingly