# Does VB.NET have an equivalent of C# auto property with custom access specifier?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I was simply wondering if in VB.Net there is a shorthand equivalent to this kind of C# including the `private` setter:

```
public string Test { get; private set; }
```

Can someone please tell me the shortest way to achieve this in VB.Net?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.net equivalent of C# Property Shorthand?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460027/vb-net-equivalent-of-c-property-shorthand)

Comment: No I was wondering if there is a way to do the private set in one line like you can in C#, turns out in VB.Net you cannot.

Comment: @Stormenet Not a duplicate. See Alex's clarifying comment.

Comment: I see, wasn't really clear from the question, I've changed that for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, this is [not possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx) in VB.NET:

> Auto-implemented properties are
>   convenient and support many
>   programming scenarios. However, there
>   are situations in which you cannot use
>   an auto-implemented property and must
>   instead use standard, or expanded,
>   property syntax.
>
> You have to use expanded
>   property-definition syntax if you want
>   to do any one of the following:
>
> - ...
> - Create properties that are WriteOnly or ReadOnly.
> - ...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't use different accesibilities for auto property accessors in VB.NET. You have to manually write the property code.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Private _test As String

Public Property Test() As String

Get
    Return _test
End Get

Private Set(ByVal Value As String)
    _test = Value
End Set

End Property
```

No alternative.