# VB.NET Public Property on a single line

Tags: c#, vb.net, properties

Is there any way I can put Public Properties on a single line in VB.NET like I can in C#? I get a bunch of errors every time I try to move everything to one line.

C#:

```
public void Stub{ get { return _stub;} set { _stub = value; } }
```

VB.NET

```
Public Property Stub() As String
    Get
        Return _stub
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _stub = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Thanks

EDIT: I should have clarified, I'm using VB 9.0.

Comment: [VB.net equivalent of C# Property Shorthand?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460027/vb-net-equivalent-of-c-property-shorthand) covers the answer - an equivalent is available as of VB10.

Comment: Yes you can use collan (:) to right multiple lines in a single line.

Comment: @djacobson: Not quite the same, as the OP isn't actually using automatically implemented properties in the code given...

Comment: @Jon Skeet The example given doesn't do anything to the field except assign/retrieve its value... That's the only case in which there exists an equivalent *one-line* property syntax between C# and VB, and that's auto-properties. Is it not so? :)

Comment: @djacobson: Yes, but that's not equivalent to the code in the question - that's what I'm saying. (I referred to automatically implemented properties in my answer, too.)

Comment: the colo has been there for a long time. I think it is even a remainder of VB6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use automatically implemented properties in both [VB 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx) and [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx), both of which will be shorter than the C# you've shown:

```
public string Stub { get; set; }

Public Property Stub As String
```

For non-trivial properties it sounds like you *could* get away with putting everything on one line in VB - but because it's that bit more verbose, I suspect you'd end up with a really long line, harming readability...

Comment: Looks like I need to be using VB version 10.0 for this (which I didn't specify or even know I was using). Thanks though.

Comment: @Fred: Right, have edited to make the answer clearer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can

```
Public Property Stub() As String : Get : Return _stub : End Get : Set(ByVal value As String) :_stub = value : End Set : End Property
```

and you can even make it shorter and not at all readable ;-)

```
Public Property Stub() As String:Get:Return _stub:End Get:Set(ByVal value As String):_stub = value:End Set:End Property
```

Comment: Wow, looks bad but at least it's not 8 lines of code! Considering I'm using VB 9.0 this is the best option. Thanks

Comment: Please consider: MAX(Readability) > MIN(Number of Lines). I wouldn't want to maintain code like the above...

Comment: it should work in VB9 it has been there since a long time. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/865x40k4%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Chrissie1 - then I must have another problem, because I get the error "Visual Basic 9.0 does not support auto-implemented properties" and other syntax errors (blue lines)

Comment: What version of VS are you using and against which framework are you compiling?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define a variable on one line, that behaves like a property, if one is willing to use a slightly different syntax, and link to a C# assembly (or play around with IL).

Tested with VS2017 and .Net 4.7.2.

The C# code (currently not available in VB.Net):

```
public class Propertor<T>
{
    public T payload;
    private Func<Propertor<T>, T> getter;
    private Action<Propertor<T>, T> setter;

    public T this[int n = 0]
    {
        get
        {
            return getter(this);
        }
        set
        {
            setter(this, value);
        }
    }

    public Propertor(Func<T> ctor = null, Func<Propertor<T>, T> getter = null, Action<Propertor<T>, T> setter = null)
    {
        if (ctor != null) payload = ctor();
        this.getter = getter;
        this.setter = setter;
    }
    private Propertor(T el, Func<Propertor<T>, T> getter = null)
    {
        this.getter = getter;
    }
    public static implicit operator T(Propertor<T> el)
    {
        return el.getter != null ? el.getter(el) : el.payload;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return payload.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then in your VB program, for example:

```
Private prop1 As New Propertor(Of String)(ctor:=Function() "prop1", getter:=Function(self) self.payload.ToUpper, setter:=Sub(self, el) self.payload = el + "a")
Private prop2 As New Propertor(Of String)(ctor:=Function() "prop2", getter:=Function(self) self.payload.ToUpper, setter:=Sub(self, el) self.payload = el + "a")
public Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("prop1 at start : " & prop1.ToString)
    Dim s1 As String = prop1
    Console.WriteLine("s1 : " & s1)
    Dim s2 As String = prop1()
    Console.WriteLine("s2 : " & s2)
    prop1() = prop1()
    Console.WriteLine("prop1 reassigned : " & prop1.ToString)
    prop1() = prop2()
    Console.WriteLine("prop1 reassigned again : " & prop1.ToString)
    prop1() = "final test"
    Console.WriteLine("prop1 reassigned at end : " & prop1.ToString)
end sub
```

This results in:

```
prop1 at start : prop1
s1 : PROP1
s2 : PROP1
prop1 reassigned : PROP1a
prop1 reassigned again : PROP2a
prop1 reassigned at end : final testa
```