# Auto Property with public getter and private setter

Tags: vb.net

**NOTE:** This is **not a duplicate** of [VB.NET equivalent of C# property shorthand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460027/vb-net-equivalent-of-c-sharp-property-shorthand). *This* question is about how to have *different access rights* on getter and setter of a VB auto-property; e.g *public getter and private setter*. *That* question is about the syntax for auto-property (and does not mention this issue).

---

I am trying to convert an auto Property (**public** getter and **private** setter) from C# to VB.NET.

But after conversion VB.NET is maintaining a private field.

C# code

```
class DemoViewModel
{
    DemoViewModel (){  AddCommand = new RelayCommand(); }

    public ICommand AddCommand {get;private set;}
}
```

VB.NET equivalent from [code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) is

```
Class DemoViewModel
Private Sub New()
    AddCommand = New RelayCommand()
End Sub

Public Property AddCommand() As ICommand
    Get
        Return m_AddCommand
    End Get
    Private Set
        m_AddCommand = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_AddCommand As ICommand
End Class
```

VB.NET code generates private backing field.

Is it possible to get rid of this back field in source code (like c#)? How?

Without this feature, VB.NET source will have lots of such redundancy.

Comment: I guess disregard that possible duplicate.  I missed the info on the private setter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using VB.NET, if you want **to specify different accessibility** for the Get and Set procedure, then **you cannot use an auto-implemented property** and must instead use standard, or expanded, property syntax.

Read MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties

---

If getter and setter **have same accessibility**, e.g. both are `Public`, then you **can use the auto-property syntax**, e.g.:

```
Public Property Prop2 As String = "Empty"
```

Comment: Note: in MSDN link, the section that says can't use auto-property syntax in this case, is "Property Definitions That Require Standard Syntax", specifically "Specify different accessibility for the Get and Set procedure. For example, you might want to make the Set procedure Private and the Get procedure Public."

Answer (score 14):

In VB.NET it's

```
Public ReadOnly Property Value As String
```

Then to access the private setter, you use an underscore before your property name

```
Me._Value = "Fred"
```

Comment: This does not work for me (compilation error). However, your solution is specified in the Microsoft docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties. I think it only works from a certain version of VB.Net.

Answer (score -1):

since the answer(s) above hold(s), you may introduce a Public Prop to expose the Private one. This may not be a nice solution but still less code, than expanded Property syntax

```
Private Property internalprop as object
Public Readonly Property exposedprop as Object = internalprop
```